# return back same partialview ViewBag not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have to show some error message on parital view and I am loading error details into ViewBag.

First time when ever paritalview load check viewbag condition is working. But when I return from controller to same paritalview "if" condition is not firing.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { name = "frmEmail", id = "frmEmail" }))
{

    <div>

       @if (ViewData["StatusDetails"] != null)
       {
        <h3>@ViewData["StatusDetails"].ToString()</h3>
       }
    </div>
```

This if condition calls first time paritialview loads. On submit button click I am calling  controller [HttpPost] method. In the controller if I get any errors I am returning back to same partial view with error details in the viewBag.

But If condition not executing and not showing error message.

```
  if (returnMessage != null)
        {
            ViewData["StatusDetails"] = returnMessage.Status == Status.Ok
                ? "No Errors"
                : returnMessage.DetailsList[0].ToString();
            return PartialView(returnMessage.Status == Status.Ok ? "_DisplayEmail" : "_EditEmail", memberProfile);
        }
```

How to pass values from controller to partial view?

Comment: You're returning one of two partial views, _DisplayEmail or _EditEmail. Do both views have the same if-statement? Also if you debug the controller action, are you seeing that the ViewData gets set correctly?

Comment: No where in you code do you use `ViewBag` (just `ViewData`) so not clear what you actually asking.